# Identity Server 3 Two Factor Authentication

Tags: authentication, identityserver3

I have to implement a 2 factor authentication solution using Identity Server. While I can find the sample code for it ([here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/AspNetIdentity_2fa)) I cannot get the sample to even prompt for 1st level authentication.

I've created a user via the admin section but I am never prompted for a sign in when I navigate back to the core/2fa route. It just jumps to the (non-existent) error page.

it seems the ctx.Environment.GetIdentityServerPartialLoginAsync() call returns null.

I am a total noob with regards to Identity Server.

Could someone please explain how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the sample itself is only the server part of the equation which explains why I did not get a sign-in prompt.

In my defense, it is Monday and I was expecting a complete example.

So, the 2 factor sample works but you will need to run one of the client samples to interact with it.